# Pandas DataFrame. Comando con data.loc funciona en 3.7 pero sale error en 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

He creado un código con datos acerca de ciudades y use la columna de los nombres de las ciudades como índice.

Al ir a seleccionar un valor de este índice, al hacerlo en Python 3.7 y poner el nombre de la ciudad si que me lo reconoce, en cambio el mismo código me da error en 3.8 diciendo que no se encuentra el valor en el índice. Pero si en cambio en vez de poner Málaga pongo 4, que es su posición si que me funciona.

```
df = DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('City',inplace=True)
a = input("Please select a City: ")
index = [a]
sample = pd.DataFrame(data.loc[index], columns = data.keys()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

El error que me arroja en Python 3.8 es el siguiente:

```
    "None of [Index(['Malaga'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Como digo en 3.7 si que me funciona.

Comment: La sintaxis correcta es `loc[fila, columna]`

Comment: Buenas @Christian, así es como lo tengo, la fila corresponde a la variable [index] y Málaga seria la fila elegida en este caso.

Answer (score 1):

Vale, culpa mía, estaba poniendo data.loc en lugar de df.loc, por lo que estaba usando los datos cargados iniciales sin modificación del índice.

Desconozco eso si por que en 3.7 si que me funcionaba estando mal.